# Programmatically comment and uncomment a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question. I have this logic in mind: I got a **JavaScript** file which contains a condition `**if** x = 0 load **index.html** else load **index1.html**`. Now, **index.html** and **index1.html** are identical and both loads the same **JavaScript** file which contains a function which should, for the condition `x = 0` take the user to the app but need to restrict some actions when `x = 1`. I'm just trying to know if it is even possible before I decide if I take this approach or completely change the logic of what I need to do. There is another way, creating two versions of the **JavaScript** file, but it would represent a significant amount of duplicated files as this commented and uncommented functions are present in more than one place on the app and as it is an **MVC** project I would have, I think, to duplicate more than the file which contains the function itself.

The idea is that I'm going to serve an app with two plans, a **FREE plan** and a **PRO plan**. The unique difference between them is a restriction on certain functionalities. So I have this function:

```
if(userActive.isPro){
                    var payActive = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("payActive"));
                    if(payActive){
                        if(parseInt(payActive.status) === 1){
                            window.location.href= '../app/index.html';
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                else{
                    window.location.href= '../app/index1.html';
                }

            }
```

And this is the function which makes the difference for each plan.

```
function openAddPopup() {
    //check first if user is PRO Copy
    const userStatus = localStorage.getItem("userKind");
    const user = userStatus;
    if (user) {
        app.router.load('contactEdit', { 'isFavorite': state.isFavorite });
    } else {
        alert("You can only add 3 elements on the free version");
    }
}
```

For the **PRO plan** I need to execute the full version of the app and for the **FREE plan** then the restricted version.

So, is it possible to append a **JavaScript** function to **index.html** and **index1.html** to, in case of the **FREE plan**, to do the second, but, in case of the **PRO plan**, the first?

Comment: It seems that you want to add security on the client side, mostly, that is impossible, these things should be done on the server.

Comment: The first function is on the server side. But the commented and uncommented are on the client side. If it is not possible to do, then what should I change on my logic? I am serving the app from a web server as a PWA.

Comment: So simply add `if (location.href.endsWith("index.html") && checkAppStatus()) {`?

Comment: Bergi, thanks, where should I add this:  if (location.href.endsWith("index.html") && checkAppStatus()) {

Answer (score 0):

As long as I woke up this morning with a simple solution in mind and want to share it with the community.

In the `index.html` I put this:

```
userStatus = 'PRO';
localStorage.setItem( 'userKind', userStatus);
```

So, in the `index1.html` this:

```
const userStatus = localStorage.getItem("userKind");
    const user = userStatus;
    if (user) {
        localStorage.removeItem("userKind");
    }
```

Then in the `app.html` this:

```
    //check first if user is PRO
    const userStatus = localStorage.getItem("userKind");
    const user = userStatus;

    if (user) {
        document.body.append("Pro version")
    } else {
        alert("Solo se pueden añadir 3 elementos en la versión Éstandar");
    }
```

How it works? When the **Auth API** send the user to the App, if it is a PRO user the **API** redirects him/her to the `index.html` which stores in `localStorage` the `userKind` variable with a `**PRO**` value, but if it is a Standard user, then the API redirects him/her to the `index1.html` which delete the `userKind` variable in `localStorage`. This way it is ensured that if user is PRO loses this condition, he/her just can access to the Standard version.

Here is a working example:

[index.html](https://www.simbiosis-dg-apps.com/appStatus-test/index.html)

Run `index.html` and then `index1.html`, as you are going to function as the Auth API.

Then comment if it is ok or have to be improved.

Comment: It is a bad idea to rely on locally stored information. One can easily write something to local storage via the developer console. All access restrictions should be verified on the server side.

Comment: Yes @trincot, I know that. The authentication and registration process of users is done on the server side and they are redirected to the app in accordance to its status. But, as the app will only be served via an **ANDROID webview app** and not via **web browser** the only access users should do to `localStorage` is to delete it all via "delete data" option and due to the nature of the the targeted users of the app, they may not even know how to do it. I relay on that. Any way, what I mainly would like to know is if my code is OK from the programming point of view.